# Power Set Proof Discrete Math If S = T, ...

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that S = T if and only if P(S) = P(T).
The P is a Power Set symbol.
I have no idea how to go about this.

Comment: You should note that this question has been asked ad nauseam before. So you can probably find the answers that are given here elsewhere on this website as well. I chose to answer, and not to vote for closure, because I felt that perhaps writing an explanation as for *what* you have to do when you approach this problem is going to be better suited.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$=$T$. Let $A\in \mathcal{P}(S)$,i.e., $A\subset S$. Since $S=T$, hence $A\subset T$ and therefore $A\in \mathcal{P}(T)$ giving $\mathcal{P}(S)\subset \mathcal{P}(T)$. A similar argument will give the reverse inequality thus establishing $\mathcal{P}(S)=\mathcal{P}(T)$.

To show the other side observe that $S\in \mathcal{P}(S)$ and hence it belongs to $\mathcal{P}(T)$ (as $\mathcal{P}(S)=\mathcal{P}(T)$) $\Longrightarrow$ $S\subset T$. Similarly $T\subset S$ thus giving $T=S$.

Answer (score 0):

You have to prove that if $S=T$ then $\mathcal P(S)=\mathcal P(T)$; and then prove that if $\mathcal P(S)=\mathcal P(T)$ then $S=T$.

1. Recall that $X=Y$ if and only if $X\subseteq Y$ and $Y\subseteq X$, meaning every $x\in X$ satisfies $x\in Y$ and vice versa;
2. $\mathcal P(X)=\{Y\mid Y\subseteq X\}$; and
3. $\subseteq$ is a transitive relation, that is $X\subseteq Y$ and $Y\subseteq Z$ then $X\subseteq Z$.

Answer (score 0):

We prove each direction separately.

$(\Longrightarrow)$: Suppose that $S = T$. Then by substitution, we immediately get that $\mathcal P(S) = \mathcal P(T)$.

$(\Longleftarrow)$: Suppose that $\mathcal P(S) = \mathcal P(T)$. We want to show that $S = T$. To do this, it suffices to show that each set is a subset of the other:

- $\boxed{S \subseteq T}$: Since $\subseteq$ is reflexive, we know that:
  \begin{align*}
  S \subseteq S &\iff S \in \mathcal P(S) &\text{by the definition of power set} \\ 
  &\iff S \in \mathcal P(T) &\text{since $\mathcal P(S) = \mathcal P(T)$} \\ 
  &\iff S \subseteq T &\text{by the definition of power set} \\ 
  \end{align*}
- $\boxed{T \subseteq S}$: Since $\subseteq$ is reflexive, we know that:
  \begin{align*}
  T \subseteq T &\iff T \in \mathcal P(T) &\text{by the definition of power set} \\ 
  &\iff T \in \mathcal P(S) &\text{since $\mathcal P(S) = \mathcal P(T)$} \\ 
  &\iff T \subseteq S &\text{by the definition of power set} \\ 
  \end{align*}

Thus, since $\subseteq$ is antisymmetric, it follows that $S = T$, as desired. $~~\blacksquare$